# Follow Us button does NOT work from PC but does work from MAC

Tags: linkedin-api

Using the same code generated by LinkedIn (from their Follow Company Plugin Generator) https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company#, myself and a colleague have very different user experiences.

In my case, using a PC and latest version of Chrome, the LinkedIn Follow Us button has no hyperlink and does absolutely nothing when clicked.

In my colleague's case, using a Macbook and latest version of Chrome, the LinkedIn Follow Us button changes to "LinkedIn: Following" after the first click and then opens a new browser tab with the BluFlux LinkedIn webpage after the second click.

Here is our Thank You page after completing a survey:
http://bluflux.com/thank-you-customer-survey-dd1/#gf_15

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you first of all checked whether any adblocking/privacy extension might have simply blocked/filtered this out …?

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  I bypassed a thorough dive into that option, but I am not sure.  No issue with other pop-ups.  No message prompt in my browser.

Comment: Do you have any specific thoughts on what I might check?